# Join more than 2000 columns

Tags: postgresql, join

Have any way to join more than 1664 columns?
Or any way to work with that many data?

My issue:

I have 4 table. And all 4 table each have 1000 columns. And each columns 10 000 rows approx.
So way much more than 1664 row...

And I like to make one search, in all of the tables.

Example:

Table 1 : 1-1000 row number,
Table 2 : 1001 - 2000,
Table 3 : 2001 - 3000
Table 4 : 3001 - 4000

If I like to search the max in the 300 column and the 1100 column and the 2500 and the 3999 column This case need to see all of the columns, how my query can find the columns.

Join not work because too many data even if I join them one small query take 30 -50 seconds...

This is my working query:

```
Select 101 as One, 230 as Two, 3200 as Three, 4000 as Four, date_trunc('minute',"TimeStamp_Table) as Timestamp_Table from "TimeStamp", "Table_1" 
 
right join "Table_2" on "Table_1"."ID_TimeStamp_FK" = "Table_2"."ID_TimeStamp_FK" 
right join "Table_3" on "Table_2"."ID_TimeStamp_FK" = "Table_3"."ID_TimeStamp_FK"
right join "Table_4" on "Table_3"."ID_TimeStamp_FK" = "Table_4"."ID_TimeStamp_FK"
where "TimeStamp" between '"2022-11-17 17:37:19"' and '"2023-01-27 11:22:00"' 
order by TimeStamp_Table;
```

This one is work, But take lot of time to run...
Also I like to put in function, so I don't know ahead which columns they have chosen...

Anything helps, thank you!

Comment: A few thousand columns seems like bad database design to me. If possible, change the design of the tables to stick to the key, value (and relevant keys) format

Comment: I think same way like you, but at this moment sadly not possible to change the design. Later I hope I get approve to remodel.

Comment: In that case, you need to see what exactly is causing the delay. First, avoid cross-joins (unless you explicitly need to combine all the data). With a left/right join, select the smaller tables (like rows) and add the large ones to them. Review what indexes are being used.
If the issues are related to slow retrieval of specific columns, use materialized views to denormalize the data into a query-friendly form

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this query in plain text? And the ddl for the indexes for these tables?

Comment: Actually you already helped. I forget to add indexes. Added now much faster. Thank you!